# Combine a SELECT and a UNION ALL

Tags: sql, oracle

Following two queries:

1.

```
SELECT idA, idB FROM tableA WHERE idA = 1;
```

2.

```
SELECT idB, value FROM tableB1 WHERE idB = <the idB result of query 1>
UNION ALL
SELECT idB, value FROM tableB2 WHERE idB = <the idB result of query 1>;
```

At the moment I'm storing the result from the first query in a variable and then execute the 2nd query seperatly, but I'm trying to combine these two queries so I only have to execute one query at all.

Query 1 returns exact one row, so we won't have multiple `idB` values. And there is exactly one entry in either `tableB1` or `tableB2` that matches this particular `idB` value.

I can't seem to find a way to combine these two queries into one, without having the data space explode in one place. For example the naive approach:

```
SELECT 
    idA, idB 
FROM 
    tableA a,
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT idB, value FROM tableB1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT idB, value FROM tableB2) b ON b.idB = a.idB
WHERE idA = 1;
```

Which means I merge two complete tables, which is obviously an overkill.

Comment: Sorry for the whole delete/undelete edits, I though I had the solution, but it turned out it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm unclear on what you want. Looks like you want to go from `idA` to `Value` through `TableA` and either `TableB1` or `TableB2`, which ever one has a matching `Value`.

```
SELECT A.idA, A.idB, COALESCE(B1.Value, B2.Value)
FROM tableA A
WHERE idA = 1;
LEFT JOIN TableB1 B1 ON B1.idB = A.idB
LEFT JOIN TableB2 B2 on B2.idB = A.idB
```

Comment: You nailed it. Thats what I was trying to do, COALESCE is new to me, thanks!